# closure with callback in javascript not working

Tags: javascript

Trying to make a function `isNameInDbId` to see if a name is in a list in mongoDB. I figured I (may?) need a closure, but I can't get it to work, it currently errors out. If I don't use a closure, the function callback doesn't know the variable `name`, or can i do this in a different way. I've tried several ways.

Code:

```
var name = "john";
var dbID = 123123123;
isNameInDbId(name, dbID, function (success) {
    if(success) {
       // log("[INFO] name is in list");
    return;
    }
});
```

Function:

```
function isNameInDbId(name, dbID, callback) {
    user_collection.findOne({_id : dbID}, (function(err, doc) {
        var names = [];
        var success = false;
        if(doc) {
            names = doc.names;
            if(names.indexOf(name))
                success = true;
        }
        callback(success);
    })(name);
}
```

Comment: That `(name)` looks wrong and should be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi said, that `(name)` looks wrong.

```js
function isNameInDbId(name, dbID, callback) {
    user_collection.findOne({_id : dbID}, (function(err, doc) {
        var names = [];
        var success = false;
        if(doc) {
            names = doc.names;
            if(names.indexOf(name))
                success = true;
        }
        callback(success);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a late night, and I had `a.indexOf(b)` with `a` and `b` around the wrong way, which prompted an unusual error saying `name` was unidentified - so I thought I might need closures.
Removing the closure and turning around `indexOf` gives the correct code as follows:

```
function isNameInDbId(name, dbID, callback) {
    user_collection.findOne({_id : dbID}, function(err, doc) {
        var names = [];
        var success = false;
        if(doc) {
            names = doc.names;
            if(name.indexOf(names))
                success = true;
        }
        callback(success);
    });
}
```